# bootstrap progress bar in angularJS using firebase to retrieve value dynamically

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, progress-bar, angular-ui-bootstrap

I need to implement a bootstrap progress bar using firebase and AngularJs.
Here are my codes in the progress.js file:

```
 .controller('progressCtrl', function($scope,$firebaseArray) {
    $scope.msg1 = false;
    var ref1 = firebase.database().ref("Points");
    $scope.data = $firebaseArray(ref1);
    console.log('progress')

});
```

My firebase structure is as follows:
[Points Node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5W6P.jpg)

I have implemented the progress bar as shown below but how to retrieve each value from the node in each of the progress bar?

```
<div class="progress" style="width: 800px">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40"
           aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="1200" style="width:40%">

      </div>
```